# Autocomplete, PHP, JS, AJAX MySql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am new to Ajax. I have Mysql database table

```
city_list 

id | city | province | country
------
1 | Calgary | AB | Canada
------------------- 
2 | Edmonton | AB | Canada
-------------------- 
3 | Toronto | ON | Canada
-------------------
```

and so on.....

`index.php`:

```
$('#city').autocomplete(
    {
        source: "searchSuggest.php",
        minLength: 3
    });
```

I want to create auto complete for the below field

```
<input type="text" id="city" name="city">
```

`serchSuggest.php`:

```
<?php
include('db_connect.php');
if($_REQUEST)
{
    $city   = $_REQUEST['city'];
    $city = ucwords($city);
    $return_results = array();
    $query = "select city, province from city_list where city LIKE '$city%'";
    $results = mysql_query( $query) or die('ok');
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($results);
        $i=0;
        while($row)
        {
        $i=$i+1;
        $return_results[$i] = $row;
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($results);
        }
        print json_encode($return_results);
}    
?>
```

This Works fine.

```
var tags = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];
            $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
                source: function( request, response ) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
                        response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
                        return matcher.test( item );
                        }) );
                        }
                    });
```

How Can i change source to the the database table city_list. Thanks.

Comment: _"Can anyone tell me from scratch..."_ -- Nop, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please try first, then come back with your code, explain what you tried and what didn't work and people may help you out.

Comment: stackoverflow.com has been helping me a lot to learn programing. I have been trying to figure this out from tomorrow. I did every search i could. and I tried lot. 
This was my first question and you vote me down. I made my request simple so that someone can help me easily. That was my point.

Comment: I didn't vote you down, I'm waiting for the code... I understand you're new that's why I posted my comment above, so you understand how SO works. We expect code in questions that ask for code.

Comment: @RAJ_India: some people may be downvoting your question as you haven't been able to _show_ that you've put the effort in, and they don't quite understand what it is that you want to do with the autocomplete.  Asking questions such as: do you want to (say) fill them in on the server side; are you going to be interacting with client-side JavaScript, and other questions like that are key to creating quality questions that people will be happy to answer.  To learn more about asking quality questions, visit the [About] page.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand you and the working of stackoverflow.com
By the way I have tried to edit my questions.

Comment: I apologize from bottom of my heart. Sorry About that.

Comment: Now, that's much better question. Only thing left is explain what didn't work, any errors, how did you debug the code? +1 for effort.

Comment: Thanks for encouragement. I could use that. The problem is it's not showing any suggestion while i type

Comment: Where's `serchSuggest.php` in your structure? Reading the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for autocomplete I see `source` expects a url, try passing an absolute path from the root, so `/folder/searchSuggest.php`

Comment: Try just returning a temporary JSON string, without the DB to test. Then try changing `source: /searchSuggest.php`. Notice the slash.

Comment: It returns the json srting
{"1":{"0":"Abbotsford","city":"Abbotsford","1":"BC","province":"BC"},"2":{"0":"Abbottsford","city":"Abbottsford","1":"BC","province":"BC"},"3":{"0":"Abord a Plouffe","city":"Abord a Plouffe","1":"QC","province":"QC"},"4":{"0":"Aberdeen","city":"Aberdeen","1":"SK","province":"SK"}}

when i type http://localhost/myestatedeal/searchSuggest.php?city=ab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with [this](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) I have not used it but going over the source code it appears it gets the pre populated values from an array. So what I would do is load all the information into an array and place it into the code it would be very simple and straight forward.

Comment: I have tried it. I mean I edited that code to use in my case. But I couldn't make it work. Thanks for your warm reply. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can return an array from the php request,then you can try the parameter of jquery autocomplete.and you can try to read the example in jquery-ui you may get the point form the website nothing more because you just fail to use the